# calling addr on global variable failing to assemble in masm32 but offset works

Tags: assembly, masm, memory-address, masm32

I literally started learning MASM32 yesterday so bear with me if this is a dumb question.

My understanding of `addr` and `offset` is as follows: both return the memory address of a variable but `offset` only works on global variables (whose memory addresses are know at assemble time) and `addr` will work on both global and local variables. I know what global and local variables are in higher level languages; my understanding is that variables declared in the `.data`, `.data?`, and `.const` blocks are global and that variable declared with the `local` keyword inside of procedures are local.

My entire code is:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

.data

szCap db "Hello", 0                   ;caption for the MessageBox
szMsg db "Hello, world!", 0           ;text for the MessageBox

.code

;Procedure for creating a MessaheBox with NULL parent and variable text
TestProcedure proc msg:dword, cap:dword     
    invoke MessageBox, NULL, msg, cap, MB_OK
    ret
TestProcedure endp

main:
    ; error on these lines
    push addr szCap ; C:\masm32\My files\HelloWorld.asm(35) : error A2008: syntax error : addr
    push addr szMsg ; C:\masm32\My files\HelloWorld.asm(36) : error A2008: syntax error : addr

    call TestProcedure

    invoke ExitProcess, 0
end main
```

However, if I change `addr` to `offset`, the code works perfectly. Why does `addr` fail to assemble in this instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In flat mode, all addresses are offsets.

The ADDR operator was added in a fairly recent version of MASM and as far as I understand is used exclusively with the INVOKE keyword. In an INVOKE, ADDR does the same as offset for global identifiers but can calculate the relative address of a local, stack-based variable as well (where it would typically emit an LEA instruction).